# Three Way Compare Variables and Strings

Tags: javascript, variables, string-comparison

So I want to compare two JavaScript variables and see if they match and are equal to a specified string. One variable is based off of user input, the other is from a database. Here is an example of what I was hoping could work...

```
var userInput = "Simple";
var databaseData = "Simple";
if (userInput == databaseData == "Simple") {...}
```

and what I know works.

```
if (userInput == "Simple" && databaseData == "Simple") {...}
```

So the first example doesn't seem to work, even with 3 equal signs instead of 2. Is what I was hoping to work possible in some other way (the purpose is simplicity and compactness) or is what I know works the best way to do it?

Comment: See, `userInput == databaseData` is a valid expression on its own, and its result is `true` (boolean). It's hard to understand that you actually wanted to ignore that - and use `a == b == c` as a completely different type of expression, true if all its parts are equal.

Comment: ((userInput == databaseData ? "Simple" :  null) == "Simple")

Comment: `userInput == databaseData == "Simple"` would equate to => `userInput == true` => `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns true if all its arguments are strictly equal:

```
function allEqual(...args) {
  return args.every((el, i, arr) => i === 0 || el === arr[i-1]);
}
```

Whether or not it makes sense to use it on three values, like this...

```
if (allEqual(userInput, databaseData, 'Simple')) { ... }
```

... is up to you.